# Cursor - Declare Select-Statement executed multiple times?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, static, cursor

I've got a question regarding cursor in t-sql. 
when i do a cursor like that, it will end up in an endless loop.

```
drop table  [dbo].[cursorcheck]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[cursorcheck](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Wert] [varchar](10) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


delete dbo.cursorcheck
GO

insert into dbo.cursorcheck 
select 'Insert'
GO


DECLARE @vendor_id int, @vendor_name nvarchar(50);

DECLARE vendor_cursor CURSOR FOR 

SELECT ID, wert
FROM dbo.cursorcheck 
WHERE wert = 'insert';

OPEN vendor_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM vendor_cursor 
INTO @vendor_id, @vendor_name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN



        insert into dbo.cursorcheck 
        select 'Insert'


    FETCH NEXT FROM vendor_cursor 
    INTO @vendor_id, @vendor_name
END 
CLOSE vendor_cursor;
DEALLOCATE vendor_cursor;
```

I'm a bit confused about this behavior. Does that mean that the select script, the cursor was declared for, is executed multiple times? i got the same effect when i insert into that table from another transaction while debugging the cursor. the problem is solved when i use the "static" keyword for declaring the cursor. but i'm confused about the behavior of the cursor when i don't use the static keyword.

any explanation?

Regards, 
Reto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is you try to read and insert the same table in loop (so it is like "a snake eating own tail"):

Cursor:

```
DECLARE vendor_cursor CURSOR FOR 
  SELECT ID, wert
  FROM dbo.cursorcheck 
  WHERE wert = 'insert';
```

And loop:

```
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    insert into dbo.cursorcheck 
    select 'Insert'

    FETCH NEXT FROM vendor_cursor 
    INTO @vendor_id, @vendor_name
END
```

For second question: *The problem is solved when i use the "static":*

> **[`STATIC CURSOR`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191286%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)**
>
> **The complete result set of a static cursor is built in tempdb when the
>   cursor is opened. A static cursor always displays the result set as it
>   was when the cursor was opened.**

and:

> The cursor does not reflect any changes made in the database that
>   affect either the membership of the result set or changes to the
>   values in the columns of the rows that make up the result set. **A
>   static cursor does not display new rows inserted in the database after
>   the cursor was opened, even if they match the search conditions of the
>   cursor SELECT statement**

Comment: thank you. yeah. that's true. but that means that the "select" statement is run again against the database and not only at the beginning, right?

Comment: @RetoWietlisbach Without `STATIC` it works on real data (like deferred execution), with STATIC it is first read once and stored in tempdb